# The PreLaunchTask "C/C++ : g++.exe" Build active file terminates with exit code 1 for cpp file when using vscode

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I use vscode for c++ programming and it sometimes report this error message. This doesn't happen to every program. However, even with the same code, sometimes it occurs sometimes it doesn't. I am sure the code has no bug.
Here is the tasks.json

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file",
            "command": "C:\\msys64\\ucrt64\\bin\\g++.exe",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        },
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "C/C++: gcc.exe build active file",
            "command": "C:\\msys64\\ucrt64\\bin\\gcc.exe",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": "build",
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

This is the launch.json

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "C/C++: gcc.exe build and debug active file",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\msys64\\ucrt64\\bin\\gdb.exe",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                },
                {
                    "description": "Set Disassembly Flavor to Intel",
                    "text": "-gdb-set disassembly-flavor intel",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: gcc.exe build active file"
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

I am only a beginner. Please help.
Thx a lot!

I have tried reinstall vscode, reboot the machine. But they didn't work.

Comment: What's the build output? It'll tell you exactly why the build failed. Please show a [mre]. If you're building c++ code with gcc instead of g++ that's likely your problem